# R long data frame and efficient way to read columns in numeric format

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, strsplit

I am working with word2vec data available at [Spanish Billion Words Corpus and Embeddings](http://Spanish%20Billion%20Words%20Corpus%20and%20Embeddings)

The dataset looks like this

```
v1   v2  v3 
once 0.1 0.2
upon 0.3 0.4
a    0.5 0.6
time 0.7 0.8
... + thousands of lines and columns ...
```

This is my code to read data but what's important are the last two lines:

```
#install.packages("R.utils")
#install.packages("readr")
#install.packages("jsonlite")
library(R.utils)
library(readr)
library(jsonlite)

##############################

# word vectors in text format 

##############################

url <- "http://cs.famaf.unc.edu.ar/~ccardellino/SBWCE/SBW-vectors-300-min5.txt.bz2"
compressed <- "SBW-vectors-300-min5.txt.bz2"
file <- "SBW-vectors-300-min5.txt"
file2 <- "SBW-vectors-300-min5.RData"

if(!file.exists(compressed)) {
  print("downloading")
  download.file(url, compressed, method="curl")
}

if(!file.exists(file) & file.exists(compressed)) {
  bunzip2(compressed, file, remove = FALSE, skip = TRUE)
}

SBW_vectors_300_min5 <- readr::read_lines(file, skip = 1, n_max = -1L)
SBW_vectors_300_min5_df = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(SBW_vectors_300_min5, split = " ")), 
                                        stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

When I run

```
SBW_vectors_300_min5 <- readr::read_lines(file, skip = 1, n_max = -1L)
SBW_vectors_300_min5_df = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(SBW_vectors_300_min5, split = " ")), 
                                            stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I get the error `invalid subscript type 'list'`

But, if I do

```
SBW_vectors_300_min5 <- readr::read_lines(file, skip = 1, n_max = -1L)
SBW_vectors_300_min5 = strsplit(SBW_vectors_300_min5, split = " ")
SBW_vectors_300_min5 = as.data.frame(SBW_vectors_300_min5)
```

I went for the last option as the thing works without error messages. The problem for the last solution is that the columns are read as factors and with factor I cannot do Principal Component Analysis unless I do this

```
index <- sapply(values, is.factor)
SBW_vectors_300_min5 <- lapply(SBW_vectors_300_min5[index], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

That thing took more than 24 hrs to compute. If I want to make it reproducible then I have to think about something much more efficient.

How can I make `SBW_vectors_300_min5_df = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(SBW_vectors_300_min5, split = " ")), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` to work?

Comment: How many levels do you have for the categorical attributes? Are the categories real numbers or actually factors, on which you intend to apply PCA?

Comment: Why are you  using `read_lines` and then `strsplit`ting on `" "` and then converting to data frame? Wouldn't it be more direct to use `read_delim(..., delim = " ")`, straight from file to data frame?

Comment: You can even use the `col_types` argument to ensure your columns are of the types you want.

Comment: @phoxis those are real numbers instead of factors

Comment: @Gregor I tried and the computer hangs :S

Comment: In general, you might want to try *not* reading the full file until you have a system that works. Set `n_max = 100` and debug while only using the first 100 rows.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor. I did that 2 days ago with a small test sample and when I found something that did work I did read the full file.